# Soma retorna NaN para valores acima de 999

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma função que calcula `subtotal + ascrescimo - desconto`, porém fui testar um valor acima de 999 ele retorna `NAN`.

```
//função para calcular o total da nota 
function calcular() {
     var soma1 = 0;
     $(".subtotal01").each(function(indice1, item1){
          var valor1 = parseFloat($(item1).val());
          //console.log(valor);
          if ( !isNaN( valor1 ) ) {
              soma1 += valor1;
          }
     });      
     //pega o valor das desconto01 e caso haja substitue a virgula por ponto
     var acrescimo01 = (document.getElementById("acrescimo01").value).replace(",", ".");      
     acrescimo01=Number(acrescimo01);

     var desconto01 = (document.getElementById("desconto01").value).replace(",", ".");      
     desconto01=Number(desconto01);      


     soma1=(soma1).toFixed(2);
     somatotal1=(soma1-desconto01+acrescimo01).toFixed(2);
     ptotal1=((desconto01/soma1)*100).toFixed(2);

     if(isNaN(ptotal1)) ptotal1 = 0;

     //substitui separador decimal ponto por virgula
     soma1=soma1.replace(".", ",");
     somatotal1=somatotal1.replace(".", ",");
     //a regex abaixo coloca um ponto a esquerda de cada grupo de 3 digitos desde que não seja no inicio do numero
     $("#total01").val((soma1).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."));    
     document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML =  '% ' + parseFloat(ptotal1);     
     $("#totalGeral01").val((somatotal1).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."));     
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Antes de substituir a vírgula por ponto, é preciso retirar todos os pontos antes. Seria: `.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", ".")`

Comment: Dessa forma?  
var acrescimo01 = (document.getElementById("acrescimo01").value).replace(".", ""); 
      acrescimo01 = (document.getElementById("acrescimo01").value).replace(",", ".");      
      acrescimo01=Number(acrescimo01);

Comment: Eu alterei o comentário que fiz. Dá uma olhada. Tem que usar um regex para retirar todos os pontos. Mas não sei se é esta a causa do NaN, mas é necessário fazer isso antes de calcular.

Comment: Nossa deu certo que vacilo. Muito obrigado, Show de bola.

Comment: Blz. Vou postar uma resposta para referências futuras. Abs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É preciso fazer um replace antes que remova todos os pontos do número, para só depois fazer outro replace que substitua a vírgula por um ponto.

Isso porque se você apenas substituir a vírgula por ponto, irá resultar em um número inválido quando houver separadores de milhar. Por exemplo:

```
6.000,00 (seis mil) virará 6.000.00(?!)
```

Com os dois replaces:

```
6.000,00 (seis mil) virará 6000.00 ✔
```

Para remover todos os pontos (`.`) possíveis do número, tem que usar uma expressão regular no replace (se usar apenas `.replace(".", "")` irá remover apenas o primeiro ponto):

```
.replace(/\./g, "")
```

O `\.` representa o ponto (usa-se o escaper `\` porque o ponto sozinho tem função dentro da expressão regular), e o `g` (de *global*) para pegar todas as ocorrências.

Em seguida outro replace simples apenas para substituir a vírgula:

```
.replace(",", ".")
```

Juntando os dois, na ordem da esquerda para a direita, fica:

```
.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", ".")
```